# Unique ID using function with every record in Insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a statement in stored procedure

```
INSERT into table(ID, name, age)
    SELECT fnGetLowestFreeID(), name, age 
    FROM @tempdata
```

The function `fnGetLowestFreeID()` gets the lowest free ID of the table `table`.
I want to insert unique ID with every record in the table. I have tried iteration and transaction. But they aren't fitting the scenario.

I cannot use Identity Column. I have this restriction of using IDs between 0-4 and assigning the lowest free ID using that function. In case of returned ID greater than 4, the function is returning an error. Suppose there are already 1 and 2 in the table. The function will return 0 and I have to assign this ID to the new record, 3 to the next record and so on on the basis of number of records in the @tempdata.

Comment: You want `NEWID ()`  function ??

Comment: What is field type of ID?

Comment: you can use Sequence

Comment: Normally using identity field is the simplest way to create unique ID numbers

Comment: I'm guessing since you say the lowest free ID that it is an int, therefore you could replace fnGetLowstFreeID() with: select isnull((max(id)+1),1) from table

Comment: Based on your comment, you can have only four rows in your table. So if table is empty and you start using your function, you should get Ids 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 - How is it different from IDENTITY ID?

Comment: Set your unique field as `IDENTITY(1,1)`

Comment: @Fabio Let's consider the example when the table is not empty as I mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tmp_City(Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1), 
Name varchar(50) , Country varchar(50), )
```

OR

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Tmp_City
MODIFY COLUMN Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1)
```

OR

Create a Sequence and assign Sequence.NEXTVAL as ID
in the insert statement

Comment: The second one is not valid TSQL.

Comment: I cannot use Identity Column. I have this restriction of using IDs between 0-4 and assigning the lowest free ID using that function. In case of returned ID greater than 4, the function is returning an error. Suppose there are already 1 and 2 in the table. The function will return 0 and I have to assign this ID to the new record, 3 to the next record and so on on the basis of number of records in the @tempdata.

Comment: @AnkitaMogha, you should put it in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a rank function like row_number and do something like this.

```
 INSERT into table(ID, name, age)
 SELECT row_number() over (order by id) + fnGetLowestFreeID(), name, age 
 FROM @tempdata
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 scenarios-

1)Show the function which you are using

2) Doesn't make sense to use a function and make it unique
still- you can use rank-

```
INSERT into table(ID, name, age)
 SELECT row_number() over (order by id) + fnGetLowestFreeID(), name, age 
 FROM @tempdata
```

3)Else, get rid of function and use max(id)+1 because you dont want to use identitiy column

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Numbers table to join the query doing your insert. You can google the concept for more info, but essentially you create a table (for example with the name "Numbers") with a single column "nums" of some integer type, and then you add some amount of rows, starting with 0 or 1, and going as far as you need. For example, you could end with this table content:

```
nums
----
 0
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
```

Then you can use such a table to modify your insert, you don't need the function anymore:

```
INSERT into table(ID, name, age)
SELECT t2.nums, t.name, t.age 
FROM (
    SELECT name, age, row_number() over (order by name) as seq
    FROM @tempdata
) t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT n.nums, row_number() over (order by n.nums) as seq
    FROM Numbers n
    WHERE n.nums < 5 AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.ID = n.nums
    )
) t2 ON t.seq = t2.seq
```

Now, this query leaves out one of your requirements, that would be launching an error when no slots are available, but that is easy to fix. You can do previously a query and test if the count of records in `table` plus the sum of records in `@tempdata` is higher than 5. If so, you launch the error as you know there would not be enough free slots for the records in `@tempdata`.

Side note: `table` looks like a terrible name for a table, I hope that in your real code you have a meaningful name :)